# Magento currency switcher not working

Tags: magento, currency

I have a Magento site but the currency switcher does not calculate the price of the products correctly in the cart. It doesn't seem to change from the base currency. The tax calculated is correct in the case of the base currency, but the subtotal and grandtotal are not correct when changed from it. What could cause this?

[image: correct with USD]
[image: incorrect with JMD]

Comment: You should write more informations about your version and perhaps important extensions you use that could cause erros.

Comment: Did you configure change rates in `System > Manage Currency`?

Comment: The version is 1.7.0.2. The only extension I've used is Fixed prices for Simple Configurable products ~> http://magento.modulabs.com/mage_en/magento-fixes-prices-simple-configurable-products.html. Yes I did configure change rates but it made no difference.

Comment: After that you rebuilt indexes?

Comment: Yes, and cleared all caches as well.

Comment: Just need to make sure:) What does your rate configuration look like?

Comment: It has one entry. Stating 1 USD is equivalent to 100.9000 JMD

Comment: Ok, for me it works out of the box with this entry in magento 1.7. Which module did you use to modify currency switcher or were just template files modified?

Comment: It's likely the template files were modified. I didn't work on this originally.

Comment: In `system config > advanced` you can check easily which modules are currently installed.

Comment: Enough worming informations out of you. It might be related to this fixed prices module. Their demostore doesn't show. Good luck!